# I Can't seem to update one part of my css. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Tags: css

Currently, I am modifying a css document to make a website compatible in IE 6 and including it using a conditional statement.  Everything is slowly starting to look as it should EXCEPT....I can't seem to modify the height of the background image in the css below. I can make it bigger by increasing the height, but decreasing the height does not make it smaller.  The original image is quite thin, so I don't see why this is a problem.

```
#title{
text-align:left;
margin-left:170px;
margin-top:0px;
background-image:url(images/gradient.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
width:680px;
height:42px;
color:white;
font-family:Helvetica, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
position:relative;
top:0px;
}
```

You can see in the attached image that the red gradient background image underneath the cork header image is too big and the text inside is too large also. However, no matter what I change in the css, it doesn't seem to alter anything.

[Image of webpage](http://www.breversdesign.com/picture5.jpg)

The div tag is:

```
<div id="title">
<h1>
    Historia    </h1>
 </div>
```

Any thoughts as to why I can't seem to change this?

Comment: fyi, if you like an answer and it solves your problem remember to mark it with the green checkmark.  If you like a contributing answer, you can upvote it as well.

Comment: Thank you.  :)  I'm still kind of new here so I didn't notice that I could do that.  Great help on this site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try first by using [firebug lite for IE](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite), that way at least you aren't guessing whats going wrong and you can identify the padding/height/etc;

My thought is that the height is simply being stretched by the `h1` element (perhaps something else sneaking in too), thats my best guess as I don't have IE6 to test, but since your height is defined for the `#title` it must be whats inside of it that stretches it.  Try setting `overflow: hidden;` for the `#title` see if that helps, or at least shows your `42px` height.

http://bodegacooperativacigales.com/historianew.html

Try firebuglite, and view the element, it will show you what to get rid of in IE.

**EDIT**
to define your h1 simply do this:

```
#title{
   text-align:left;
   margin-left:170px;
   margin-top:0px;
   ...
}

#title h1 {
   height: 20px;
   margin: 0; // remove margin
   padding: 0; // remove padding to check if this is the issue
}
```

in your IE6 CSS sheet. Don't set a background image into the `h1`.  The above piece is separate from your `#title` css definition.

Comment: That sounds like a fantastic resource Jakub. I will definitely try it out.  Thanks!  I use a macbook pro, but I am testing on an old PC.  Can I download it on the mac to test IE or does it need to go onto the pc?

Comment: @user1187043, you don't need to download, you include the JS in your page (just like you would jQuery), just take a read. I find its a good tool for silly IE6 stuff

Comment: The overflow: hidden; trick worked for the gradient image but I still can't seem to change the size of the font within the h1 element. Is there a css workaround so I don't have to change that h1 element on each webpage?

Comment: Well, it did fix the font size, although it seemed to break something else in the css.  http://www.breversdesign.com/picture6.jpg

Comment: updated answer again... ;) I'm guessing you just added `h1` to your `#title` css definition, make it its own.

Comment: I tried a different method for defining the h1 element. I used .h1fix {
font-family:Helvetica, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
text-align:left;
padding: 1px 0px 1px 5px;
margin:0;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold; 
display: inline;
}                                                                  And then added "<h1 class="h1fix">" to the webpage and it seems to be working fine now.  Thank you SO much for all of your help and patience with me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be having issues regarding the height due to the child element creating overflow. Try adding the following rule to prevent the parent element from displaying any overflow:

```
#title {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Jim, that seemed to work!  Although now I still can't seem to change the font size for the word "Historia".  Is that because of the header html tag? Do you know if there a workaround so I don't have to remove that html tag in my webpage?

Comment: @user1187043, you will have to define your `h1` tag for IE6, thats the problem it seems as Jim & I have identified. So just define the height, etc in your IE6 css file.

Comment: well, I tried adding "font-size:12px;" to the css, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: ah...I misunderstood.  I'm not sure that I know how to define a h1 tag with css.  I'm sorry for the stupidity.

Comment: I finally for it working!  Thank you so much for all of your help.  :)